# Implementation of slide gesture like is done in the call log list view

Tags: android, listview, gesture

In the call log, there is a feature that when you slide one direction it will call the number and in the other direction message the missed number.  In each case the missed number in the list view is pushed aside by either "Call" with a green background or "Message" with an orange background.  I think this is really need and would like to implement this type of interaction in an app.

First question, what is the actual term for this operation?  Is this a fling, swipe, slide, etc.?

Second question.  I have seen sporadic code snippets for handling fling gestures in list views but not a solid unified example for what I am looking for.  Perhaps I am just not searching using the right terms.   In any respect, does anyone know of a solid example implementing the functionality (i.e. handling the user input, painting the widget, etc.) ??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's called a "fling" gesture. Question [937313](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) has a bunch of great links, code snip its and further information.